# CRUD Working with JQGrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jqgrid

I am trying to implement CRUD in JQGrid. But I am having  following issues:

-Rows can't be added using Add Button separately [Only possible in inline mode]

- Delete row causes postback, even with EditDialogSettings.ReloadAfterSubmit set to false.
- Deletes only the rows added after inline editing. How is it possible to delete a row in client side?

I want the grid to be bound on page load. All edits after that should occur in client side only. Once form is finally submitted grid changes will be handled.

I am following the Documentation provided in [this link](http://www.trirand.net)  but I am not able to implement it.

Any help on this issue is highly appreciated.

---

**Update:** 
Here is the sample code I have written:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Trirand.Web" Namespace="Trirand.Web.UI.WebControls" TagPrefix="trirand" %>
<trirand:JQGrid ID="XYZ" runat="server"  Width="700px" showToolBar="true">
<columns>
<trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="AA" HeaderText="AA" Width="20" Editable="true" DataType="local"/>
<trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="BB" HeaderText = "BB" Width ="50" Editable="true" DataType="local" />
<trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="CC" HeaderText ="CC" Width = "20" Editable="true" DataType="local"/>
</columns>
<ClientSideEvents RowDoubleClick ="editRow" />     
<ToolBarSettings ShowInlineAddButton="true" ShowInlineCancelButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true" />
</trirand:JQGrid>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var LastSelection;
  function editRow(id) {
    if (id) {
      var grid = jQuery("#<%= XYZ.ClientID %>");
      grid.restoreRow(LastSelection);
      grid.editRow(id, true);
      LastSelection = id;
}
}
</Script>
```

I am able to do inline editing, add a row on the top. But I am not able to delete the row seen on table XYZ after data binding is done. I hope this code gives you an idea regarding the problem.
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try their support forums?  Isnt this a paid product?
http://www.trirand.net/forum/

Answer (score 0):

When start with jqGrid was some hard but to the end i can understand it

Change property datatype to "local"

create the columns, some how

```
jQuery("<GridName>" or this).jqGrid(
  { datatype: "local",
    colNames:['column_title_0','column_title_1','column_title_2'], 
    colModel:[  {name:'column0',index:'column0', editable:false,editoptions:{readonly:true,size:10}},
                {name:'column1',index:'column1', editable:false,editoptions:{readonly:true,size:10}},
                {name:'column2',index:'column2', editable:false,editoptions:{readonly:true,size:10}}],
    viewrecords: true,
    width: 400,
    mType: "POST",
    caption:'JQGrid review',
    height: '50px',
    scroll: 1
  }
);
```

Get row by id

```
     rowData = $(<Grid name or this for current grid>).jqGrid('getRowData',rowId);
      if(rowData)
      {
        rowData.Property
      }
```

Add row

```
  $(<grid id> or this).jqGrid('addRowData', <Here.Model.Id>, <object with all properties>);
```

Delete Row by Id

```
  $("<grid id>" or this).jqGrid('delRowData',rowId);
```

Current Row selected

```
  var selRowIndex = $("<grid id>" or this).jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
```

I recommend you a turn for http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html it have good examples

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. I have already set dataType="local". But it is not working for me. I have followed the demo illustrated in http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html. I am using inline add method. So I could add a new row and delete it. But I am not able to delete a row that I obtained in Jqgrid after databinding. Any suggestion to simplify my problem is highly appreciated.

Comment: update your question and specific which is the problem put part your code. with it we just can have slight idea

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code I have written:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Trirand.Web" Namespace="Trirand.Web.UI.WebControls" TagPrefix="trirand" %>
<trirand:JQGrid ID="XYZ" runat="server"  Width="700px" showToolBar="true">
<columns>
<trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="AA" HeaderText="AA" Width="20" Editable="true" DataType="local"/>
<trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="BB" HeaderText = "BB" Width ="50" Editable="true" DataType="local" />
<trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="CC" HeaderText ="CC" Width = "20" Editable="true" DataType="local"/>
</columns>
<ClientSideEvents RowDoubleClick ="editRow" />     
<ToolBarSettings ShowInlineAddButton="true" ShowInlineCancelButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true" />
</trirand:JQGrid>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var LastSelection;
  function editRow(id) {
    if (id) {
      var grid = jQuery("#<%= XYZ.ClientID %>");
      grid.restoreRow(LastSelection);
      grid.editRow(id, true);
      LastSelection = id;
}
}
</Script>
```

I am able to do inline editing, add a row on the top. But I am not able to delete the row seen on table XYZ after data binding is done. I hope this code gives you an idea regarding the problem.
Thanks!